# Internet explorer 6-8 not loading my site properly

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, loading

RESOLVED. The rendered fonts using @font-face declarations in IE 6-8 were causing the website to not load properly. The fonts were eot's. Basically after a few page loads on IE6-7 the browser would stop painting the pages. It usually didn't load at all in IE8.

I have a conundrum that I would love some help with...

My website, http://www.vulytrampolines.com/, loads mostly fine in modern browsers. However, in IE 6-8, it, for lack of a better word, **DIES**!

Examples:

- Loading http://www.vulytrampolines.com/ sometimes loads all the
  content/css/js of the page, but IE doesn't paint it (i.e. so the user
  sees a competely white page or a completely orange page [our background is orange]). If I ctrl+a and ctrl+c to select all
  and copy, the clipboard has all the text of the page! But you can't see it. A ctrl + f5 of
  the page usually fixes it.
- After changing between a few pages from the navigation at the top, IE stops painting the page and leaves you stuck viewing the previous page (and you can't scroll). If you ctrl+a and ctrl + c and put that in a clipboard, it is the new pages content, but you can't see it.

Unfortunately about 35-45% of our customers use IE6-8 at any given time, so I'd really like someone who might know the best way to debug this, or any solutions on what is actually wrong...

Comment: Welcome to the number one problem of web development.

Comment: Haha... yes, I know this all too well, but I've never actually had this specific issue before lol.

Comment: @Benno in Firefox + Firebug under profiler it has problems loading `http://www.vulytrampolines.com/css/DINNeuzeitGroteskStd-Light.woff`. Could be it this?

Comment: Can you please isolate the problem further? This description is too generic, would require significant amount of time to require study your code. In any case it sounds like not-closed float problem.

Comment: I'm using IE 8.0. I'm behind a proxy that stops some sites, for example FB. When your site tries to load `connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js` it receives an html page (from my proxy) and stops loading. Perhaps this is one of the problems.

Comment: @xanatos: It was the fonts. IE7 just doesn't like loading them at all.